How to enable only specified application(s) to run with SeLinux/AppArmor?
I'm using Vanilla Linux (5.4.x, 4.9.20) under x86 and AArch64.
My customer requires that only specific applications will run.
If an attacker (for example) will try to run his own application, it will not run.
Is it possible to achieve it with AppArmor or SeLinux?
If yes, can you please tell how?

If a remote malicious user has the ability to transfer and attempt to execute an application they likely already have access to a privileged user necessary to grant them the ability to execute that application.  Limiting or completely disabling SSH access is probably the best way to secure a system.
